# How do I see git added files?

Tags: git, git-add, git-stage

Sometimes I run `git add .` and big files that weren't supposed to get added are added. How can I see which files were added without commiting? And how to 'un-add' those files or all files at once so I can fix the `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(Disclaimer : none of the commands below modifies **your changes in files**, all this is about what's staged or not)*
**How to...**

...display the full list of what's staged at this point. ([doc for diff --staged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--cachedltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203))
`git diff --staged --name-only`

..."un-add" (unstage) *one* file
`git reset -- path/to/file`

...or similarly, unstage a directory with everything in it
`git reset -- path/to/dir/`

...unstage everything ([example in the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-Undoadd))
`git reset`

...and last but not least, the "unstage wizard"! (interactive unstaging, which goes chunk by chunk like it does for `git add -p`)
`git reset -p`

---

Finally, about fixing your `.gitignore`, take a look at [`git check-ignore -v <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to know specifically which `.gitignore` file ignores your path.

Answer (score 8):

#### How to check which files staged

`git status -s`

[image]
Files with a green M letter prefix indicate that they have been cached, And red 
 means it is still in the workspace, not cached.

Answer (score -2):

> And how to 'un-add' those files

Use `git rm` *your-file*. For details, see the [documentation of git](https://git-scm.com/doc) or try `git rm --help`

Comment: Be careful: `git rm` removes *both* the *index* (aka staging area) copy of the file *and* the work-tree copy. Typically one might like to keep the work-tree copy, for which one must use `git rm --cached`.